# Unexpected 500 Internal Server Error on file upload when code hasn't changed

Tags: flask, file-upload, internal-server-error

I'm running into an unexpected 500 Internal Server Error when I don't believe I've changed the relevant code. I've tried reverting to a previous version of the same code (when it was working) without issue.

It is only occuring when trying to upload a file and doesn't return any debug messages that I've been able to capture.

Code below:
HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="/picture" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
<input type="submit" value="Upload!">
</form>
```

Flask code

```
# Upload File Configuration
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
```

```
# Set Profile Photo
@app.route('/picture', methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def upload_image():

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect("/profile")

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No image selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = (str(session["user_id"]) + '_' + secure_filename(file.filename))
            rows = db.execute("SELECT profile_photo FROM users WHERE id=:id", id=session["user_id"])

            #if user already has profile picture
            if rows[0]["profile_photo"] != None:
                os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], rows[0]["profile_photo"]))

            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET profile_photo = :filelocation WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"], filelocation=filename)

            rows = db.execute("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, postcode, bio, hobbies, profile_photo FROM users WHERE id = :id",
                          id=session["user_id"])

            filename = rows[0]["profile_photo"]

            flash('Profile picture updated!')
            return render_template("profile.html", rows=rows, filename=filename)

        else:
            flash('Photo not updated - allowed image types are -> png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
            return redirect("/profile")
```

It was working before so I'm surprised at the sudden reversion. I'm new to flask so any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you write ```allowed_file``` function yourself or are you using any third party libraries? Can you share that? Also can you share your config file without any passwords and important info. It is very well be an issue of a folder not present. In other words you might have to create the folder!

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma I've included the code above. No third party libraries. The folder should be working as existing profile photos that have been uploaded through that function are still being displayed.